# Invoke-WebRequest: TimeOutSec property is not working

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I am using Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet to check whether a website is up and running after turning on VMs. Usually, It takes 10-15 mins as windows services are set to delayed start. I am using while loop with 3 attempts and 300 sec for TimeOutSec parameter. However, My 3 attempts in loop get over within 3-4 mins. it didn't last for 15 mins. What's missing? Any suggestion? I could use Start-Sleep but that's not standard in this context.

Here is the sample code:

```
$retryCount = 3
while ($true)
{
try {
    $Response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $serviceUrl -TimeoutSec 300 -UseDefaultCredentials -UseBasicParsing
    Write-Host "$serviceUrl is up and running.'"
    break
}
catch {
    Write-Host "Windowservice set to delayed start. Trying again..."
    Write-Host $_
    --$retryCount

    if ($retryCount -eq 0)
    {
        Write-Host "$serviceUrl might not up yet. Please check from Browser."
        break
    }

}
}
```

I am using PowerShell 5.1 version. Above script works fine when service is already started or if I put start-sleep for 3 minutes in loop.

I am trying to start TFS service and following exception is caught in catch block:

```
TF246018: The database operation exceeded the timeout limit and has been cancelled. Verify that the parameters of the operation are correct.
```

Comment: Are you locking out the account be try too many times?  Add a sleep to the loop : https://ss64.com/ps/start-sleep.html

Comment: No. Even a single Invoke-WebRequest request with timeoutsec of 900 sec doesn't work. it does work with start-sleep but it's something hardcoded. I want to use Invoke-WebRequest as different URLs will have their own up time.

Comment: You account has to be valid on both client and server for DefaultCredential to work.  Does code work after server is running?

Comment: Then why doesn't it work before the service starts?  From cmd.exe >Netstat -a which will give status of the connection.  If a connection already exists than you cannot open another.

Comment: not sure. however, if i put start-sleep for 3 mins in try block, invoke-webrequest does work in last attempt. let me check if there is some info in exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found an answer myself. The reason being Invoke-WebRequest is timed out before the given time is TFS service had returned exception. After throwing exception for certain time, TFS is up and running. That's why it was difficult to debug this issue. I had also confirmed the same behavior from browser while checking manually.

In summary, There is no issue with TimeoutSec property of Invoke-WebRequest. However, such scenarios could be common and we can't just rely on TimeoutSec parameter.